# "opening" a website in android device

Tags: java, php, android, web

I'd like to just like to execute a php code on my website, which writes something to a file. Is there a simple solution for android development?

Comment: You understand that PHP runs in server side and not in client side, right?

Comment: yea i want to write the file to the server :)

Comment: The platform from which you access your site should be largely irrelevant to the behavior of your php scripts.  Are you trying to write something to this file based upon what platform is accessing it?  More information would be a big help.

Comment: So how's android involved? Will you start the application server on an android device or what?

Comment: yea i'm running a linux server and try to run the exec command over php on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing you want to trigger the execution of a certain php script on your server from an Android phone:

```
String url = "http://whatever.com/script.php?argument=value";
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

try {
    client.execute(new HttpGet(url));
} catch(IOException e) {
    // something happened
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.helllo.com"));
startActivity(browserIntent);
```